# Retrieving deleted text within a note on my iPhone

Tags: iphone, text, notes.app

In my iPhone notes, I had created a "note" and had lots of text typed in there. By mistake, I deleted most of the text I had typed inside of the "note". Is there a way I can retrieve that text? I did not delete the whole note, only text inside the note was deleted, so what I want to know is if I can recover that text or not.

Answer (score 1):

iPhones have an Undo function. By default, to trigger the undo option you need to give your phone a quick shake. In your case it *may* be too late to use it.

To find out, go into your note and then give the phone a quick shake. If it works you will get an option such as the one below:

[image]

Obviously, then you would tap on Undo to undo the last *typing* action.